LabVIEW Driver for Princeton Applied Research 5302 Lock-In Amplifier
I'm working in a lab that uses a Princeton Applied Research 5302 Lock-In amplifier.  The device has a GPIB port, and I wanted to interface the device with LabView.  Does anyone know where to get a good driver to accomplish this?

LabVIEW has a GPIB driver built in. You can find the functions in the Functions -> Instrument I/O -> GPIB palette.
Just refer to your hardware documentation for all the commands, that is, chapter 9 of: https://www.ameteksi.jp/-/media/ameteksi/download_links/documentations/supportcenter/signalrecovery/instruction_manuals/221490-a-mnl-f.pdf
The following is an excellent resource for LabVIEW related questions: https://forums.ni.com/
